# Refactoring Asynchronous Email Sending in Flask-Security-Too after Removal of send_mail_task

Tags: python, flask

I am currently working on a Flask application that uses Flask-Security-Too for handling user authentication. In my previous implementation, I used the @security.send_mail_task decorator for sending emails asynchronously. However, after updating Flask-Security-Too, I noticed that this decorator has been deprecated.

Here is a snippet of my current implementation:

```
from flask_mail import Mail

mail = Mail()


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # Deprecated decorator usage
    @security.send_mail_task
    def delay_security_email(msg):
        with app.app_context():
            send_security_email(msg)

    def send_security_email(msg):
        # Use the Flask-Mail extension instance to send the incoming `msg` parameter
        # which is an instance of `flask_mail.Message`
        with app.app_context():
            mail.send(msg)
```

Any advice or code examples that could help me refactor this to work with the updated Flask-Security-Too would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a decorator function that async any function without know params or kwarg.

```
import threading
from functools import wraps

def async_action(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()

    return wrapped
```

now, if you want to async function. use this decorator. Ex:

```
@async_action
def send_security_email(msg):
```